# Read NTFS compressed file from disk, skip caches

Tags: windows, caching, memory, disk

I am trying to write a small app that will start the timer, read every file in folder, and stop the timer when everything is in memory.

For "normal", uncompressed files this works rather well, by openining file with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. Sadly NTFS compressed files seem to be cached somewhere as readings get faster and faster the more I run the program.

I have tried RamMAP and cleaning standby memory, but the results are rather inconsistent, as windows decides to refill the caches as fast as possible.

How can this be done? How can I ensure that NTFS compressed file is read from disk and uncompressed on the spot.

Comment: *"How can this be done?"* - You haven't told us, what *"this"* is.

Comment: Reading the file from disk while skiping windows standby cache... Everything works fine when I am reading a normal file, but when it is compressed windows doesn't seem to care which flags I specify or if I call flushfilebuffers.